# Change of measure for Poisson process with deterministic intensity

Tags: probability, measure-theory, poisson-process

Consider a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$, deterministic in time. A change of measure on a Poisson process impacts its intensity. Is there a way, by change of measure, to convert the Poisson process with deterministic intensity to a Poisson process with constant intensity?

What would the Radon-Nikodym of this change of measure be?

Does anyone know the answer to this? Is it even possible?

Comment: On every finite time interval $[0,T]$, the RN density can be written easily (simply write down each density with respect to the Lebesgue measure and compute the ratio). On $[0,+\infty)$, the measures are mutually singular hence the RN density does not exist.

Comment: ...Thus: Which one are you asking about? :-)